# Android : How to populate a ListView with alphabet indexer and fastscroll as in contacts app.?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

I would like to implement a ListView with fastscroll and albhabet indexer as in the contacts application. I'm using a SimpleAdapter to populate the ListView. As seen from the image, by selecting a letter from the alphabet indexer at the right, the listView  selection goes to the corresponding ListItem. How to accomplish this? Please help.

[image]

Comment: [Here is an example android project with alphabet scroll and section header.](https://github.com/amalChandran/ListviewAlphabetIndexer)

Answer (score 5):

As I can't see your posted image, but I think

Here is the way to **implement Section Indexing** in Android as iPhone has,
You should also refer Sectionindexer & alphabetindexer for such custom implementation.

1. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders
2. https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView
3. http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html

Try this, Hope this what you need..

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry to say that the I am unable to download the tutorial from first link. The page doesn't get displayed do to some issue. And the second link, I have already tried to customize it. But it still doesn't serve my purpose. Anyway, thank you for your answer. Please do update if you find any other interesting solution.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is late, Still here is a my [github repo](https://github.com/amalChandran/ListviewAlphabetIndexer) with an android project with list section header and alphabet indexer. I also implemented filter in it. Hope it helps someone.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the relevant bits of code to your post?

Answer (score 0):

I will let you know in brief.

Create a class extends RelativeLayout implements OnTouchListener

Define  a strings of alphabets

Find the screen height of list view

Create dyanamic textviews count same as number of alphabets, height of textView ==> screenWidth / alphabets.

Override onTouch method .

Find the textview which is currently selected//Offset.

Create a handler for sending the event to mainList

Call Listview setSelectionFromTop method pass the position.

Its done...

Comment: It is better to use `AlphabetIndexer` with `ListAdapter`