# ListView with Separators

Tags: android, listview, separator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : How to populate a ListView with alphabet indexer and fastscroll as in contacts app.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414650/android-how-to-populate-a-listview-with-alphabet-indexer-and-fastscroll-as-in)

i need to do a listView with separators. It's easy, but I also need that separators have this behavior:

[image: ListView Separators]

The separator doesn't disapear until the next separator reachs it.

How can I do it?

Comment: you have to create custom latout for this.

Comment: Nirav, the problem is that the separators are inside the list view, but also they overlap the listView items.

Andro selva, in this post they created the index. I am searching the overlaping of the separators

Comment: This is the answer of my question:

http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/